# Binding controls inside ASPxGridview?

Tags: aspxgridview

I have an ASPxGridview, inside there is a DataItemTepmplete, it contains a ASPxRadioButtonList and a three ASPxCheckBoxList. on the SelectedIndexChange of the radiobuttonlist i bind a single checkboxlist based on some values. The first time it gives no error and binds perfectly, when i change the value of the radiolist a javascript error occuer which is:

Microsoft JSCript runtime error: parentNode is null or not an object.

I have tried ups down and wasted a whole day trying to figure-out what is the problem but nothing so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think the postback that occurs after the first SelectedIndexChanged event breaks something in your page.
Try using the ClientSideEvents of the ASPxCheckBoxList instead.